# Can I create separate variables for duration and pitch in LilyPond and combine them?

Tags: notation, lilypond, lily-scheme

How would I go about defining two separate variables where one can be mapped onto the other to produce some typical output? For instance:

```
durations = {
  4 8 8 2
}
pitches = {
  e' g' f' a'
}
\score {
  ...something goes here...
}
```

To get something like this:

[image: e'4 g'8 f'8 a'2 in LilyPond]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a popular snippet to do exactly this, https://lsr.di.unimi.it/LSR/Item?id=654